# Ambiguous definition error while trying to define Eq for custom Tree data structure

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement `Eq` and `Ord` for the Huffman tree data structure, but I'm getting several "ambiguous definition" and scope related errors. I've been following the tree example on https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

```
import Data.List

data Tree a = Leaf a Int | Internal (Tree a) (Tree a) Int deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where
(Leaf a ac) == (Leaf b bc) = (a == b) && (ac == bc)
(Internal (Tree a1) (Tree a2) ac) == (Internal (Tree b1) (Tree b2) bc) = 
                    (a1 == b1) && (a2 == b2) && (ac == bc)
_ == _ = False

instance Ord (Tree a) where
Tree a <= Tree b = (freq a) <= (freq b)

freq :: Tree a -> Int
freq (Leaf _ c) = c
freq (Internal _ _ c) = c
```

I'm not sure what is ambiguous. It says `==` might be from `Prelude` or my code. However, my == is defined only for my `Tree` so I'm not sure what's going on. Please help me understand and rectify this issue.

Comment: You are deriving `Eq` and `Ord` for `Tree`. Then why are you writing instances of it ?

Comment: Apart of what bheklir have said you are pattern matching using Tree, But Tree is a type constructor not a Data constructor. You can only pattern match using the data constructors Leaf or Internal

Comment: @Sibi I might be misunderstanding something, but my understanding is that Eq and Ord are interfaces, and I'm providing the concrete implementation of Eq and Ord. I come from a Java background.

Comment: In Haskell You have 2 options: you automatically derive the instances of the classes (using derive) or you write the instances yourself. Here You are first deriving them automatically then providing an implementation for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indentation.  You need to indent all lines with `==` and `<=`.  The compiler sees `instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where` as one block, then the definition for `==` on trees as completely separate blocks of code.  Indent this and your `Tree a <= Tree b = ...` line, and it should be good to go.  Otherwise, it looks like you're defining `==` at the top level of your source code, which Haskell happily lets you do.

Since you're already deriving `Eq` and `Ord` for `Tree`, you don't have to define them yourself.  If you want custom instances here then *don't* derive them.  Aside from that you need to fix the definition for your `Ord` instance to just be

```
instance Ord (Tree a) where
    a <= b = freq a <= freq b
```

with the same definition for `freq`.  You don't need to do pattern matching here, especially since `Tree` is a type constructor, but you can only pattern match with data constructors.  `Leaf` and `Internal` are data constructors here, so they can be pattern matched on.  You'll need to fix this for your `Eq` instance too, but the solution is similar.